# Partial class delegation in Kotlin

Tags: multiple-inheritance, delegation, kotlin

How do I partial delegate methods/fields in Kotlin?

To be specific: here I am trying to inherit class `User` from interface `TraitA` and implement field `marked: Boolean` in the wrapper `StateA`. That would clean up the `User` implementation, because `marked` is just a state field. Note that `TraitA` can't be a class because I want to use several such interfaces: `User() : TraitA by StateA, TraitB by StateB, ..`

```
/* does not compile (Kotlin M12) */
interface TraitA {
    var marked: Boolean

    fun doStaffWithMarked()  // must be overridable
}

class StateA() : TraitA {
    override var marked = false
}

class User() : TraitA by StateA(){
    override fum doStaffWithMarked() {
        //...all fancy logic here...
    }
}
```

The alternative is to implement all in one place:

```
class User() : TraitA{
    override var marked = false // ugly code

    override fum doStaffWithMarked() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Is there a way/pattern that would solve that problem with easy and as little code as possible? Code/bytecode generation is not an option for me.

*UPDATE*

I was not very clear about that, but please note that `doStaffWithMarked()` is ***unique*** for every `User`.

So I may suggest a 'half-bad' solution with run-time assertions:

```
interface TraitA {
    var marked: Boolean

    /* must be overridden */
    fun doStaffWithMarked() = throw UnsupportedOperationException()
}

class StateA() : TraitA {
    override var marked = false
}

class User() : TraitA by StateA() {
    override fum doStaffWithMarked() {
        //...all fancy logic here...
    }
}
```

The question is still open, since a really good solution would check that `doStaffWithMarked()` at compilation time.

Comment: isMarked() in TraitA seems redundant. You can just access marked as it is.

Comment: `isMarked()` does a lot of fancy staff and must be overridable for every end user

Comment: I dont think this will be possible anytime soon, because StateA isnt really a full class, you cant instantiate it without providing an implementation for doStaffWithMarked(), so StateA is useless on its own.And having some classes like User which is a complete class and StateA which is an incomplete class is very strange and will be hell to typecheck i guess

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Split up `TraitA` into two interfaces, then delegate the one and implement the other:

```
interface TraitA {
    var marked: Boolean
}

interface TraitAPlus : TraitA {
    fun isMarked(): Boolean
}

class StateA() : TraitA {
    override var marked = false
}

class User() : TraitA by StateA(), TraitAPlus {
    override fun isMarked(): Boolean {
        return marked
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be cool to support such a pattern on the language level. Not sure what it would look like, though.

Comment: Kotlin's motto is making things explicit. I guess the compiler could allow you to delegate interfaces to incomplete implementations but this solution makes it obvious what is delegated and what is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that just inherites from `StateA` instead of delegating but that's not very nice:

```
interface TraitA {
    var marked: Boolean

    fun isMarked(): Boolean
}

abstract class StateA() : TraitA {
    override var marked = false
}

class User() : TraitA, StateA() {
    override fun isMarked(): Boolean {
        return marked
    }
}
```

And here's a somewhat unusal approach where I delegate `TraitA` to an anonymous instance of `StateA`

```
class User() : TraitA by object : StateA() {
    override fun isMarked(): Boolean {
        return marked
    }
} {

}
```

To be honest though, I'd rather rethink the design of the class hierarchy instead. In particular, you can put method implementations in interfaces (but not property values) so if `isMarked()` only depends on `marked` you could just put the implementation for it directly in `TraitA`. Your code then becomes:

```
interface TraitA {
    var marked: Boolean

    fun isMarked(): Boolean {
        return marked
    }
}

class StateA() : TraitA {
    override var marked = false
}

class User() : TraitA by StateA() {

}
```

Edit: Separate answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30914383/615306

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as you said, those approaches are not very nice. The last one is not what I need since `isMarked()` should be overridable (see update). The first one with classes kills the whole idea of multi-inheritance. The second one with anonymous objects works, but it is *supper* ugly.

Comment: I agree. Could you split up TraitA into two interfaces, so that you can delegate one of them and implement the other? See my edit.

Comment: Bingo! It works, and I am able to scale it: http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/oofhklfiv3hi54r971le3l1tth/7pc2m0b7nnkpg766kplfhq3m9v

Comment: Could you please extract the last solution into a separate answer, so I would mark it as correct? Thank you.